# Kubernetes resource cert path

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to learn kubernetes and for the Kube core resources like APIServer or controller manager [ Considering the cluster has been created via kubeadm], If I look at the config yaml file located at /etc/kubernetes/manifest. I see that we pass the cert or key path in the command like below :-

--etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt

We then also specify the path in the pods volume like below

- mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki
  name: k8s-certs

volumes:

- hostPath:
  path: /etc/kubernetes/pki

My question is what is the  need of passing the cert path with name in the command when it is ultimately getting read from the volume?

Comment: Did the provided answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Location of cert file on the node `/etc/kubernetes/pki/`
- That folder on the host is mapped/mounted inside the container at location  `/etc/kubernetes/pki` (  `mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki name: k8s-certs` && `hostPath: path: /etc/kubernetes/pki`)
- so in the command `--etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt` is not referring to directory on the node , it is directing towards the path inside the container. in short it is reading from the volume not directly from node directory.